# How to dynamically slice Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a month array in javascript, for example:

```
2012/09/01,2012/10/01,2012/11/01,2012/12/01,2013/01/01,2013/02/01,2013/03/01,
2012/09/01,2012/10/01,2012/11/01,2012/12/01,2013/01/01,2013/02/01,2013/03/01,2013/04/01,
2012/09/01,2012/10/01,2012/11/01,2012/12/01
```

What I wanna separate the Array is that:

```
if (monthArray[i] > monthArray[i + 1])
   // slice the Array.
```

So, for the above example, I should get 3 new Arrays. They are:

```
Array1: 2012/09/01,2012/10/01,2012/11/01,2012/12/01,2013/01/01,2013/02/01,2013/03/01

Array2: 2012/09/01,2012/10/01,2012/11/01,2012/12/01,2013/01/01,2013/02/01,2013/03/01,2013/04/01

Array3:2012/09/01,2012/10/01,2012/11/01,2012/12/01
```

I know it is easy to do it if we know specific length, my question is, how to do it if we dynamically get a month Array(it may be divided into n groups). How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Can you rewrite your question? I cannot understand what do you want to do.

Comment: What is the algorithm you are using to select how many elements are to be put into each new array? What is the criteria determining which elements go into which array?

Comment: Are you saying you want to pull out all the months from the date arrays?

Comment: Hi Ginden. Thanks for your reply. You can see that the original Array is actually made by 3 subarray groups, if I wanna use monthArray[i] > monthArray[i + 1], right? So, if I have another array which has the same format like the example showed and it is made by n sub array groups. How can I slice it into n arrays? Thanks!

Comment: For everyone who doesn't understand the question: he wants to split the original array in strictly monotone increasing sequences.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you want to end up with an array of arrays, then just do it with a for loop...

```
var result = []; //this will contain multiple arrays once finished
var currentArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < monthArray.length; i++) {
    currentArray.push(monthArray[i]);
    if (i < monthArray.length - 1 && monthArray[i] > monthArray[i + 1]) {
        result.push(currentArray);
        currentArray = [];
    }
}
result.push(currentArray);

//result[0] is Array1
//result[1] is Array2
//result[2] is Array3
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wxa9r/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any better way than to iterate over the array to build your slices:

```
var arr = ['2012/09/01','2012/10/01','2012/11/01','2012/12/01','2013/01/01','2013/02/01','2013/03/01','2012/09/01','2012/10/01','2012/11/01','2012/12/01','2013/01/01','2013/02/01','2013/03/01','2013/04/01','2012/09/01','2012/10/01','2012/11/01','2012/12/01'];

var slices = [];
var start = 0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (check(arr, i)) {
    slices.push(arr.slice(start, i+1));
    start = i+1;
  }
}

function check(array, index) {
  if (index+1 === array.length) return true;
  return Date.parse(array[index]) > Date.parse(array[index+1]);
}
```

This solution has the advantage that it doesn't build the slices one element at a time, instead it builds them one slice at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an array-of-arrays as a result, you can do this with `.reduce`:

```
var partitions = dateList.reduce(function(rv, month) {
  var partition = rv[rv.length - 1], prevMonth = partition[partition.length - 1];
  if (!prevMonth || prevMonth < month)
    partition.push(month);
  else
    rv.push([month]);
  return rv;
}, [ [] ]);
```

Starting from a list of partitions with one (empty) partition, this just checks the last month in the last partition to see if it's smaller than the current month under examination.  If so (or if we're on the very first one), we add the month onto the partition. If not, then a new partition is started, containing just the current month.